# I want to join two tables, removing duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to say I'm an amateur on MySQL, plus english is not my mother's language.

Here is my first table "Teacher":

```
ID Name         Procedence
1  John         Italy
2  Mike         Russia
3  Lauren       Spain
4  Arnold       Spain
```

And here my second table "Course":

```
ID1  CourseName
1    Sailing
1    Football
2    Basketball
2    Hockey
```

I would like to know which country has more teachers giving courses, but I don't want that it count the same teacher twice. So far I made this:

```
SELECT Procedence, Count(Procedence) as Procedence_Count 
from Teacher INNER JOIN Course
ON Course.ID1 = Teacher.ID
GROUP by Procedence
having Procedence_Count > 1;
```

When I run this, I obtain:

```
Procedence    Procedence_Count
Italy         2
Russia        2
```

But the code counts John and Mike as two persons, I would like to remove that duplicity, so I would like to obtain:

```
Procedence    Procedence_Count
Italy         1
Russia        1
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select Procedence, Count(distinct t.id) as teacher_count 
from Teacher t join
     Course c
     on c.ID1 = t.ID
group by Procedence
having teacher_count > 1;
```

One additional note:  "procedence" is not at all a common  English word.  One word is "provenance".  I think more commonly "origin" or just "country" would be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for your correction! I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jusep Please 'accept' this answer if you consider the problem to be resolved